# Is there a way or a built in R function that can sum the values of duplicate names within a list?

Tags: r, list, duplicates, names

lets say I have this list:

```
values <- list(2, 8, 3, 21, 54, 2, 43, 31)
countries <- list('US', 'UK', 'China', 'US', 'Russia', 'UK', 'US', 'China')
names(values) <- countries
```

Then, values looks like:`('US' = 2, 'UK' = 8, 'China' = 3, 'US' = 21, 'Russia' = 54, 'UK' = 2, 'US' = 43, 'China' = 31)`

Is there a built-in function in R or some short way to add the values of the duplicates? 
Meaning, to make values become: `('UK' = 10, 'China' = 34, 'Russia' = 54, 'US' = 66)`
(The order doesn't matter though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(values) %>%
    unnest(c(value)) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
    deframe %>% 
    as.list
#$China
#[1] 34

#$Russia
#[1] 54

#$UK
#[1] 10

#$US
#[1] 66
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
as.list(tapply(unlist(values), names(values), sum))
#$China
#[1] 34

#$Russia
#[1] 54

#$UK
#[1] 10

#$US
#[1] 66
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
as.list(with(aggregate(values ~ ind, sum, data = stack(values)), 
             setNames(values, ind)))

$US
[1] 66

$UK
[1] 10

$China
[1] 34

$Russia
[1] 54
```

Comment: That's great! I was fiddling and trying with aggregate() for so long and couldn't figure it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(unique(countries), function(x){sum(unlist(values[names(values)==x]))})
```

also works. At first i did not see that you had lists.